How to make a subclassable pipeline in scala
I have inherited a scala codebase that looks like so:
  class Pipeline[T] {
    def start(args:mutable.Map[String,Any]):T
    def process(t:T, args:mutable.Map[String,Any]):T 
    def finish(t:T, args:mutable.Map[String,Any]):T

Start calls process, which calls finish.
args is used so subclasses can update the map so downstream functions can pull those values out of the map.  So if it's a building pipeline, subclass it so you have a library pipeline, and it can pass the number of books along.  Terrible structure that makes gotos look good.  Plus, this code is threaded and he mutable map is leading to threading problems.
I want to change this so each function accepts an args class with fields, and can, if it needs pass a new value to a downstream function, subclass it to add that field via a copy constructor, then the downstream function gets the subclass and can just access the value it needs via a method.  No type problems, no threading issues.
Turning out to be nightmare to get past the type checker though. When we subclass to get a new pipeline, it never converts to a base pipeline, we only subclass to supply functionality.
But i can't define, for example, process as taking a [T2 <: ArgsClass] and returning a [T3 <: ArgsClassWithBookCount] because overriding for a specific subtype doesn't work.
I think this must be a pattern that has been solved, but i don't know it.

Could you show some example? I am not sure how to interpret subtypes in the context of this pattern. Do you have a deep class hierarchy? Do you use decorator pattern? Or maybe it's only about subclasses of T?

You may use a kind of builder pattern and modify inputs and outputs
with typical functions like map or contramap, so you can finally run them all combined when all the types match.
Something like below - a minified example from a real project:
final case class PipeBuilder[DownstreamF[_], UpstreamF[_], DownstreamOutput, -Input, Output](
  downstream: DownstreamF[DownstreamOutput],
  upstream: Input => UpstreamF[Output]
):

  def run(using F: FlatMap[DownstreamF],
    sk: SameKinds[DownstreamF, UpstreamF],
    st: DownstreamOutput <:< Input
  ): DownstreamF[Output] =
    downstream.flatMap(r => sk(upstream(st(r))))


Ignore the higher-kinded types if not using any effects
